# Who is Oshino Ougi?

Tags: monogatari-series

This question contains spoilers for the second season of the Monogatari series.

Oshino Ougi refers to herself as the niece of Oshino Meme. But Kaiki mentions in Koimonogatari/Hitagi End that Meme has no family at all and it's not possible that he has a niece.

Also, [this news-article at ANN](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/news/2014-03-12/owarimonogatari-final-novel-promo-streamed) suggests that she ([or he?](http://bakemonogatari.wikia.com/wiki/Ougi_Oshino#Trivia)) fights with Koyomi in the latest novels and it seems to me that she is responsible for Nadeko becoming a god. Is she actually an antagonist?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ougi’s true identity is Araragi Koyomi himself. From the Bakemonogatari [Wikia's](http://bakemonogatari.wikia.com/wiki/Owarimonogatari) section on "Ougi Dark":

> Gaen reveals that Ougi’s true identity is Araragi Koyomi himself. She is an Oddity that Araragi created, similarly to how Hanekawa’s stress created Black Hanekawa, and Sengoku’s hallucinations created the white snake Kuchinawa. Ougi represents Araragi’s self-criticism. When Araragi saw "Darkness" for the first time in Shinobu Time, he realized that there is a law dictating over the world of Oddity. Araragi knows that he is too weak, too hesitant, too emotional to make harsh decisions, and he subconsciously wished for a being that can judge him, and "correct" everything wrong in this world. His desire came true as Oshino Ougi.

Comment: Welcome to Anime and Manga. can you quote the section of the page which supports your answer incase if the link was to go down (and also there's a lot of text on that page)

Answer (score 3):

As I haven't read the light novel, it still very vague whether she is an antagonist or not. As in Nisemonogatari, Kaiki is an antagonist, but in the Second Season, he's become somewhat of a protagonist.

For now in *Monogatari Series: Second Season*, I believe she's antagonist from the fact that she lied and said that she is Meme Oshino's niece. (She pretend to be a good guy)

When she almost crashes into Nadeko, she said something like "I'm not supposed to meet you yet" and tells Nadeko to stop playing the victim. This implies that she's related to Nadeko becoming a snake god.

> On very last episode when Kaiki gets attacked by someone. That someone mentions about Ougi, implying that she is the one behind Kaiki's attack. And when Kaiki about to pass out, he remember that name (Ougi), but he couldn't recall who is that. This means that Kaiki is telling the truth about Ougi not being Meme Oshino's niece.

Comment: Kaiki seems somewhat of an airhead when it comes to people he hasn't dealt with before. I wouldn't be so sure him not remembering her tells us anything about her and Meme's relationship.

Comment: In addition to the above, it's also worth noting that Kaiki even lies in the narration about not knowing Senjougahara very early on before he meets her in Okinawa.

Answer (score 2):

In short, yes she is the main antagonist of the series, as you as for most parts of the series Araragi solved the problems of the other girls, in Kizu it was for Shinobu, in Neko it was for Hanekawa, Bakamonogatari - Senjogahara and the other girls etc.

So Ougi is "Araragis problem", or it's manifestation.

It is a big spoiler, I mean her identity

> she is Araragi, or rather Araragi's dark side.